# Are Children of the Red King and the Magician Trilogy set in the same universe?

Tags: children-of-the-red-king

The series *Children of the Red King* and the Magician Trilogy (*The Snow Spider* etc.) are both by Jenny Nimmo. The first features the descendants of the Red King, one of the most powerful magicians in history, each of whom possesses at least one unique power. The second chronicles the adventures of Gwyn, a boy descended from the great Welsh magician Gwydion.

Interestingly,  Charlie Bone, the central protagonist of *Children of the Red King*, is also descended from a Welsh magician,  in this case Mathonwy.

Are the two series set in the same universe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Very likely

There were certainly more magicians than Gwydion in Wales. Gwyn is the descendant, not only of Gwydion, but from other magicians. Indeed, Gwyn is also descended from Math, and thus from Mathonwy, [who was his father](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Math_fab_Mathonwy):

> "Time to find out if you are a magician, Gwydion Gwyn!" said Nain.
>
> "A magician?" Gwyn inquired.
>
> "Time to remember your ancestors: Math, Lord of Gwynedd, Gwydion, and
> Gilfaethwy!"
>
> —*The Snow Spider*

This does not prove that this is the same  version of Mathonwy referenced in *Children of the Red King*, but it is certainly a strong sign.

However, we have a stronger indication. In the second book of *Children of the Red King*, Charlie Bone acquired a wand that had belonged to his ancestor Mathonwy:

> It was then that he saw the wand. It had to be a wand, for it couldn't
> be anything else. A slim white stick lay behind one of the huge books.
> It was about half a meter long with a pointed silver tip. Charlie
> picked it up.
>
> "You can't have that," said Skarpo sharply "It doesn’t belong to me."
>
> "Whose is it, then?" asked Charlie. The wand was cool and smooth, and
> it seemed to fit into his hand as if it belonged there.
>
> "I stole it," said Skarpo. "It belonged to a Welsh wizard. It'll be
> of no use to you at all."
>
> —*Charlie Bone and the Time Twister*

The wand is white and made of ash:

> Mathonwy sighed. From the folds of his cloak he drew out a slim ash
> stick: his wand. "What would you have me do?"
>
> —*Charlie Bone and the Hidden King*

But Gwyn appears to have used a very similar wand!

> "Now take my ash wand and see what you can make of it!"
>
> It was a slim uncomplicated stick, and yet it had released a cloud of
> magic.
>
> —*The Chestnut Soldier*

This is a wand of ash that belonged to an ancient Welsh magician, much like Charlie's wand. It probably cannot be the same one, since both wands were destroyed (or in the latter case transfigured), but it is of the same ilk.

Given the similarity of both protagonists being descended from the same Welsh magicians, who used very similar wands, it seems likely that the books are set in the same continuity.